# Do i have to create appenders for all classes in log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm using log4j for my final project. I tested it using single class before I used log4j in my project. That worked fine.
Then I added log4j to my project and I used it in many classes using:

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Supplier.class);
```

Then I got a warning:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (classes.Supplier).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

This is my properties file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, errorfile

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.errorfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\HardwareLog\\INFO.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.errorfile=C:\\HardwareLog\\ERROR.log
log4j.appender.errorfile.Threshhold=ERROR
log4j.appender.errorfile.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.errorfile.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.errorfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.errorfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

1. Do I have to create appenders for each class to use it?
2. Can I use one properties file in different packages ?

Comment: You do not need to create an appender for each class. See Caladian answer at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495443/how-to-implement-use-log4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495443/how-to-implement-use-log4j) on how to implement log4j

Comment: Usually you create appenders for a package, not a single class. If you create an appender for a package, that appender is applied to all the classes in that package as well as all the classes in all the subpackages of that package.

Comment: Thank you all for quick response

Comment: You are welcome  :o)

Comment: So how can i solve thar warning no appenders clould found .... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I removed root logger and added two loggers for my two packages.

```
log4j.logger.package1=DEBUG,FIRST
log4j.logger.package2=DEBUG,SECOND
```

now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can go for **root logger** that will log for the entire application.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
```

plese go through this link
https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/